# Maximal p-subgroup of inertia group.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

We know from the theory that if $\mathbb{L}$ is a finite Galois extension of the local field $\mathbb{K}$ then the ramification group $G_1$ is a $p$-group where $p$ is the characteristic of the residue field of $\mathbb{L}$.

Furthermore $G_1$ is a normal subgroup of $I$ the inertia group of $\mathbb{L}$/$\mathbb{K}$.

Is it true that $G_1$ is the largest $p$-group contained in $I$ ? If it's true, can i use this to show that $G_1$ is the biggest $pro$-$p$-group contained in $I$ when the Galois extension $\mathbb{L}$/$\mathbb{K}$ is infinite?

Comment: Yes it is true. In the case of a finite extension, $I/G_1\hookrightarrow k_L^*$ where $k_L$ is the residue field of $L$. In particular, $\#(I/G_1)$ must be prime to $p$, so $G_1$ must be the largest $p$-group contained in $I$.